# TouchEvents across different Android Tablets

Tags: android, touch

I have an application that does calculations based on the size of the user's touch. I am using getSize() in the MotionEvent class to do this. The Android API states that: "This represents some approximation of the area of the screen being pressed; the actual value in pixels corresponding to the touch is normalized with the device specific range of values and scaled to a value between 0 and 1".

I've tried this application on three different tablets and I've got three very different results.
In one tablet, it works as expected, with values ranging between 0 and 1. 
In another tablet, the size property is not reported back and all I get is 0.
In the third tablet, the size property is very high; it goes up to 3.1. Even though a value is returned, this is problematic because by the API definition, the touch size can go up to 310% of the screen size. And if these values don't go by the API definition, they are just arbitrary values that I cannot really use.

Is there another way to get the touch size, which is normalized across most tablets, that I can use for my calculations?